# Source Qualifier SQL Override Error with Mapping Variables

Tags: etl, informatica-powercenter, informatica

I am using a mapping variable of date/time data-type and aggregation MAX
In Source Qualifier SQL Override i am giving 
`select col1,col2 from tbl where col1>$$dt`

(col1 is also date data type)

When i am validating the query it is giving Invalid Query and
error was 
`[Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-00933 : SQL command not properly ended`

I have also done extraction of characters like 
  `select col1,col2 from tbl where to_char(col1,'DD-MM-YY')>to_char($$dt,'DD-MM-YY')`
but still the same same

I am not getting what the error is and the same thing if i am trying for number column the it is validating fine and performing incremental extract also.

Any suggestions regarding the same will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have used something like this below and it worked.

col1 > (TO_DATE('$$dt','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you cant use mapping parameters/variables etc in source qualifier query (like you are trying).

However you can build the complete query outside, and pass it in using $$SQ_QUERY, effectively overriding the complete SQL statement.

Comment: I have used mapping variables(integer data type) before in Source Qualifier and its working fine !!

But the thing is when i am using date-time mapping variable it is giving above error .

Can u plz give some more details about building query outside and passing it